# Attaching jQuery library in lightining component causing an error on Summer 16

Tags: lightning-aura-components, jquery, lightning, summer-16

I'm using jquery as static resource.

```
<ltng:require scripts="/resource/jquery/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" />
```

In firefox it throws an error:

> TypeError: fn is undefined throws at
>   https://light-demo-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/XyhLNaMJXc3t5qwu_xzuTA/aura_proddebug.js:14073:9

I've also tried older version of jQuery 1.12.4
Result is the same. Also error thrown in chrome:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'expando' of undefined throws at /resource/jquery1/jquery-1.12.4.min.js:5:8159

Also attempted to add lates jQuery version 3.0.0
In Firefox it throws error:

> TypeError: d.implementation is undefined throws at https://light-demo-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/c/demo_app_development.app:6:18148

In Chrome:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'createHTMLDocument' of undefined throws at /resource/jquery3/jquery-3.0.0.min.js:6:18166

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Jquery 2.2.4 both minified and not.
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'createHTMLDocument' of undefined throws at /resource/CPQ_JQuery:6:17503

Comment: @MaciekSimm : I'm having the same issue any resolution on this?

Answer (score 1):

After summer 16 release, we need to change the code to include the external JQuery/Css files from static resource. Here is an example of the same:

```
<ltng:require .... scripts="{!$Resource.JQuery}" />
```

Here JQuery is the static resource name, and this static resource is having only single JS File.

For a zip file having multiple files/folder follow another syntax:

```
<ltng:require ....  scripts="{!join(',', 
    $Resource.jsLibraries + '/jsLibOne.js', 
    $Resource.jsLibraries + '/jsLibTwo.js')}" />
```

More details you can find in  following salesforce doc:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_libs_platform.htm

Answer (score 0):

The issue with expando in 1.x is known and under investigation. 2.2.4 does not have any known issues currently and is passing our tests so I am not sure what is going on there. jQuery 3 just released in the past few days and we have not had a chance to even try it ourselves yet.

Can you retry your examples using the non-minified versions - this should not fix anything but hopefully will provide a better error?

Comment: Actually if to use non minified version of jQuery 2.2.4 - error is gone. Switching back to minified version will cause error to reproduce again. Clearing cahce doesnt help. Also to mention - this occurs in debug mode. If to switch debug mode off - another error is thrown : `code`TypeError: v is undefined throws at https://light-demo-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/XyhLNaMJXc3t5qwu_xzuTA/aura_prod.js:493:77

Comment: I just did a quick check with jQuery 2.2.4 and jQuery-ui-1.11.4 with locker service enabled. The component loads up perfectly in chrome, IE and Firefox. But the several UI widgets like Date picker are not working as expected. In Firefox :TypeError: elem.ownerDocument is undefined
in IE and chrome :Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'defaultView' of undefined

Comment: @TojiKano Any solution on this?